# missing blob with jgit

Tags: kotlin, jgit

I am trying the following with jgit:

```
val git = Git.open(File("/path/toMyRepo"))
val diffFormatter = DiffFormatter(DisabledOutputStream.INSTANCE).apply {
        setRepository(git.repository)
}

git.diff().call().forEach {
    if (it.changeType == DiffEntry.ChangeType.MODIFY) {
       diffFormatter.toFileHeader(it).toEditList().forEach {
            println(it)
       }
    }
}
```

but I am getting a the following exception:

```
    "org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing blob 9645ba8461cd88af20fd66a3e44055deb24f826e"
```

Does anyone see what is wrong with the code?

EDIT: full stacktrace with a quite empty repo (only one commit and a change on the only line in the only file):

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing blob f7891cbde46bbb6ca96065ecf1900ef6a223f679
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.diff.ContentSource$ObjectReaderSource.open(ContentSource.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.diff.ContentSource$Pair.open(ContentSource.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffFormatter.open(DiffFormatter.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffFormatter.createFormatResult(DiffFormatter.java:950)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffFormatter.toFileHeader(DiffFormatter.java:915)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt:17)
```

Comment: Where does the exception occur? Please provide the full stacktrace.

Comment: now providing the full stacktrace

Comment: Sounds like an inconsistent Git repository. What happens if you run a similar operation with the normal Git binaries? If that works, I'd report a bug at JGit at Eclipse.org

Comment: I created a new git repo that is quite empty. Don't think it is an inconsitent repository

Comment: A known bug in JGit: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=544894

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will be helpful, but I lost some time in this issue and if someone falls down this hole in the future: It appears to be some issue in the `DiffFormatter` class when the latest changes which you are trying to diff are not committed.

My use case was to get the changes of a single file, and to make it work, I made use of the gitDiff interface directly, like so:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

String filename = "mafile.java";

Git.open(File("/path/toMyRepo")).diff() // calling diff command 
        .setPathFilter(PathFilter.create(filename)) //setting to just look for changes in specific file 
        .setContextLines(0) // just the changes itself, not the bordering lines
        .setOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream) // the outputstream to print the changes
        .call();

System.out.println(byteArrayOutputStream.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```